# Can I load both obj and materials as an MDLAsset?

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit, apple-model-io

I have a directory containing an obj, mtl, and the textures. If I do

`let asset = MDLAsset(url: url)` then it loads the mesh, but no textures. Now, if I go rename the `model.mtl` file to `model.abc` and run the same code, I get the following on the console

`020-10-08 19:24:36.277305-0700 ModelLoader2[1607:11820939] Unable to find mtl file /Users/myname/Documents/ModelLoader2/Models/model/model.mtl`

What this tells me is that `MDLAsset` does find the mtl file, but it doesn't properly load the textures. Is there a way to get it to load the textures as well? I see some protocol called `MDLAssetResolver` with the following definition, but absolutely NO documentation on the internet and [0 useful hits on github](https://github.com/search?q=MDLAssetResolver)

```
public protocol MDLAssetResolver : NSObjectProtocol {

    
    func canResolveAssetNamed(_ name: String) -> Bool

    func resolveAssetNamed(_ name: String) -> URL
}
```

My question are,

1. what is the best way to load obj files? I had intended to use Model I/O so I could export to `.usdz` and other formats
2. Is Model I/O not worth dealing with investing time into, or should I move on to other methods? It seems like there were a few WWDC talks hyping it up as a powerful framework, but so far it seems useless due to the lack of documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried asset.loadTextures() since you already loaded the asset ?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).